# compactness - show that there an absolute max

Tags: calculus, compactness

This is a practice question from "Advanced Calculus, Folland. Chapter 1.7 Q.4)

Suppose $\quad S\subset { R }^{ n }\quad $   is compact  $\quad f:S\longrightarrow R\quad $    is continuous  and $f(x)>0$ for every $x\quad \epsilon \quad S\quad $. Show that there is a number $c>0$ such that $f(x) \ge c$ for every $\quad x\quad \epsilon \quad S\quad $

So this is what I understand :

$S$ is compact that means it is closed and bounded,

$f$ is continuous so $f$ has an absolute max and an abs min.,

so would  $c$ just be our absolute min.

If I am not correct please help. If I am right how would I show this ?

Comment: I think that you misstated the conclusion: it should be that $f(x)\ge c$ for each $x\in S$. And yes, $c=\inf f[S]=\min f[S]$ will work fine.

Comment: yes you are right editing it right now. Thanks again Brian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have all of the necessary pieces. You know that since $S$ is compact, there is a point $p\in S$ such that $f(p)\le f(x)$ for each $x\in S$. Let $c=f(p)$ by hypothesis $f(p)>0$, so $c>0$, and $f(x)\ge c$ for all $x\in S$.

Comment: Thanks Brian this is a very nice proof its very easy to understand. :)

Comment: @KjTada: You’re welcome. But note that you really had all of it: you just needed to fit the pieces together right.